# Im getting an error when trying to release my soundPool

Tags: android, release, soundpool

I am trying to release my sound pool but i do not know very well what i am doing. Have I released my sound pool object correctly?

I am getting an error on this bit of code, the bit within the "" marks: 
    int sampleId = "(int) v.getTag();" - why is this? How can I correct it?

Also have I released my sound pool correctly?

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements  View.OnClickListener ,  SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener {

SoundPool Clubb1;
Integer currentBtnId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
    Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);

    Button buttonA = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    Button buttonB = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    Button buttonC = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    Button buttonD = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    Button buttonE = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
    Button buttonF = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
    Button buttonG = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonG);
    Button buttonH = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonH);
    Button buttonI = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonI);
    Button buttonJ = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonJ);

    buttonA.setTag(R.raw.clubb1);
    buttonB.setTag(R.raw.clubb2);
    buttonC.setTag(R.raw.clubb3);
    buttonD.setTag(R.raw.clubb4);
    buttonE.setTag(R.raw.clubb5);
    buttonF.setTag(R.raw.clubb6);
    buttonG.setTag(R.raw.clubb7);
    buttonH.setTag(R.raw.clubb8);
    buttonI.setTag(R.raw.clubb9);
    buttonJ.setTag(R.raw.clubb10);

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonC.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonD.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonF.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonG.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonH.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonI.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonJ.setOnClickListener(this);

    Clubb1.setOnLoadCompleteListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(currentBtnId != null){
        Clubb1.release();
    }

    currentBtnId = v.getId();
    int sampleId = (int) v.getTag();
    Clubb1.load(getActivity(), sampleId, 1);
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
    switch (currentBtnId){
        case R.id.buttonA:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonB:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonC:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonD:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonE:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonF:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonG:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonH:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonI:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonJ:
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag is an object. put an Integer from xml or set tag from java

```
buttonA.setTag(1);
buttonB.setTag(2);
buttonC.setTag(3);
buttonD.setTag(4);
buttonE.setTag(5);
buttonF.setTag(6);
buttonG.setTag(7);
buttonH.setTag(8);
buttonI.setTag(9);
buttonJ.setTag(10);
```

int id = (Integer) v. getTag ();

int sampleId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("clubb"+id, "raw", this.getPackageName());

Clubb1.load(getActivity(), sampleId, 1);

Comment: how would i do this code into my project? would i just put int sampleId = (Integer)v.getTag(); into my xml?

Comment: You just want raw resource w.r.t button click right?

Comment: I just need my 10 buttons to play the 10 different sound clips that correspond to each button when they are clicked but I'm getting that error on the tag bit of the .java code. Where would I need to place the bit of code you've made into my code? I'm not very good at programming so please help me and explain what to do and where to put it all.